# Random variables mean task

Tags: probability

So let's say we have a bag that has 5 balls marked with numbers 2 2 2 3 3. One of the ball got lost, but we don't know which. The probability of the lost ball is random, so it can ether be 3/5 or 2/5 depending on the mark. Then we take a random ball from the urn, X is its' number. Whats the random variable mean of this X?

As far as I think, we have scenarios where we pick a ball and its' number is 2 and probability is 2/4, then number 2 again probability 3/4, then number 3 with probability of 2/4 and number 3 with probability of 1/4.

We do 2*2/4+2*3/4+3*2/4+3*1/4, is this the correct way or do we need to add probabilities of which ball might be lost, so we add 3/5 or 2/5?

Comment: Without knowing the mark of the lost ball, E(X) cannot be computed. Are we supposed to assume that the lost ball was chosen uniformly randomly? Then this should be specified in the text of the exercise.

Comment: @Did Yes we don't know which ball got lost. I presume everyone would accept it as being random on which ball got lost?

Comment: Would they? What is your source for this?

Comment: @Did Alright you win, I edited the post

Answer (score 2):

After you take a ball from the urn, there are a few possibilities for the contents which are all equally likely. (_ will stand for the ball taken).

_ 2 2 3 3

2 _ 2 3 3

2 2 _ 3 3

2 2 2 _ 3

and
2 2 2 3 _

Because possibilities are equally likely, you can take the average of the balls in each possible urn and average those values.
E[_ 2 2 3 3] = (2+2+3+3)/4 = 10/4

E[2 _ 2 3 3] = 10/4

E[2 2 _ 3 3] = 10/4

E[2 2 2 _ 3] = (2+2+2+3)/4 =9/4

and
E[2 2 2 3 _] = 9/4

Take the average of those and get (10/4 + 10/4 + 10/4 + 9/4 + 9/4)/5 = 48/20 = 2.4

Another way to think of it is that the first ball you pull out doesn't really matter.  The second ball is the only one recorded in the average, and any ball is equally likely to be the second.  The average there is (2+2+2+3+3)/5 = 2.4

Answer (score 0):

There's a Law of Total Probability.   Let $X$ be the number of the ball picked, $Y$ that of the ball lost.
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) & = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y)) \\ & = \mathsf P(Y=2)\,\mathsf E(X\mid Y=2)+\mathsf P(Y=3)\,\mathsf E(X\mid Y=3) \\ &= \tfrac 35\cdot (\tfrac 24\cdot 2+\tfrac 24\cdot 3)+\tfrac 25\cdot (\tfrac 34\cdot  2+\tfrac 14\cdot 3)\\ &= \tfrac {14}5\end{align}$$